# permission denied while running sass from zsh

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I just ran apt-upgrade, might have messed something up.

trying to run sass I get:

```
zsh: permission denied: sass
```

trying to run gem same thing:

```
zsh: permission denied: gem
```

anyone know what might be causing this?

Comment: Where are `sass` and `gem` in your path? What is your path (`print $path`)? Do a `whence -av sass` to see which is being accessed. Are they just stubs from your ruby manager or bundler? Did Ubuntu update a path to the version they actually point to? You might want to add a _ruby_ tag to this.

Comment: I have the same issue with Babun on Windows. I created an Alias that works for gem `alias gem="C:/Program\ Files/Ruby/bin/gem"` but the same for sass doesn't work. However access permissions are similar.